# Convert a custom helper without LinqExpression to one using LinqExpression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom helper that works.

*Custom helper without LinqExpression* (this is working)

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper html, byte[] image)
 {
   var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(image));
   return new MvcHtmlString("<img src='" + img + "'  />");
 }
```

*Using above custom helper* (this works)

```
@Html.Image(item.Picture)
```

I am trying to re-write the same custom helper using LinqExpression.

I have come up with the following code, but TModel and TValue are not being recognized in Visual Studio and also I am not sure how to get the `byte[]` value passed to this custom helper i.e. set the value of variable `databaseImge`.

I am getting following compile time errors when using the LinqExpression version of the custom helper.

> The type or namespace name 'TModel' could not be found...
>   The type or namespace name 'TValue' could not be found...

**Question** : What am I missing in my method and how would I get the value of `item.Picture` passed to this helper?

*Custom Helper with LinqExpression* (this is giving compile-time error)

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatabaseImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{

  //TModel model = (TModel)helper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model;
  //var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression,htmlHelper.ViewData);
  var dastabaseImg = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
  var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(dastabaseImg));
  return new MvcHtmlString("<img src='" + img + "'  />");
}
```

I would like to use the above LinqExpression helper, by using the below code, where item.Picture returns a byte[].

```
 @Html.DatabaseImage(modeItem => item.Picture)
```

Comment: But there is no reason to do that, what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: `(modeItem => item.Picture)` what is the point of using a lambda method if you're going to ignore the `modeItem` variable anyway?

Comment: @Evk, In my view all helper method calls are using a LinqExpression but the one for Image is not. I would like  uniformity in  my view as far as calling helper methods are concerned. That was my motivation behind this.

Comment: Ok, but at least don't pass `Expression` there. All you do is immediately compile and call it, so pass just `Func<TModel, byte[]>` instead: `DatabaseImage<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<TModel, byte[]> func)`

Comment: @Evk, that sounds like a good idea too. Then within the helper method, how would I access the byte[] value?

Comment: I've posted answer with an example (and updated it, because realized it's better to extend generic `HtmlHelper<TModel>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your method needs to be

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatabaseImage<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
```

You should then use

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression,htmlHelper.ViewData);
byte[] dastabaseImg = metadata.Model as byte[];
var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(dastabaseImg));
return new MvcHtmlString("<img src='" + img + "'  />");
```

Comment: Thanks.Let me try it.

Comment: I am gettting a compile-time error at `htmlHelper.ViewData` saying `ViewDictionary cannot be converted to ViewDictionart<TModel>`

Comment: Also, at the line that has `metaData.Model` it gives a compile-time error saying `Cannot be converted to TModel`

Comment: Oops - forgot `<TModel>` in  `this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper` - see edit

Comment: Now the second error still remains at the line that has metaData.Model. it gives a compile-time error saying Cannot be converted to TModel

Comment: Sorry I not sure what you mean - its an object so you would need to cast it, for example `var dastabaseImg = metadata.Model as byte[];` (I assume that is what you want)

Comment: I have these 2 lines yet it now gives a run-time error. ` var dastabaseImg = expression.Compile().Invoke((TModel)metadata.Model);
            var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(dastabaseImg as byte[]));`

Comment: No, the code I suggested is `var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData); var dastabaseImg = metadata.Model as byte[];` (then your `var img = ...` code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160793/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sunil).

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I need to now understand exactly what's happening.

Comment: It seems that  metaData.Model always means the expression we are returning from right hand side of LinqExpression. So `(modelItem => item.Picture)` would mean metaData.Model is the data represented by item.Picture.

Comment: I added some additional notes to chat, but yes, the LHS is the model in the view (as defined by your `@model` declaration, and the RHS is the property of that model your accessing)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `Expression` here, because all you do with it is compile and invoke.Instead, pass `Func<TModel, byte[]`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatabaseImage<TModel>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<TModel, byte[]> func) {            
    var dastabaseImg = func((TModel) htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
    var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(dastabaseImg));
    return new MvcHtmlString("<img src='" + img + "'  />");
}
```

You will have to call it like this:

```
@Html.DatabaseImage<YourModelType>(modeItem => modeItem.Picture)
```

or

```
@Html.DatabaseImage((YourModelType modeItem) => modeItem.Picture)
```

It's better to extend generic `HtmlHelper<TModel>` by the way, like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatabaseImage<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Func<TModel, byte[]> func) {            
    var dastabaseImg = func(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);
    var img = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(dastabaseImg));
    return new MvcHtmlString("<img src='" + img + "'  />");
}
```

Then you can call it easier:

```
@Html.DatabaseImage(modeItem => modeItem.Picture)
```

Comment: I tried your first version, but it gives a run-time error saying `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCAppNorthWind.Models.Category]' to type 'MVCAppNorthWind.Models.Category'.`

Comment: @Sunil that means your model is `List<Cat‌​egory>` and you are calling `Html.DatabaseImage<Category>()`. I suppose your are doing that inside some foreach loop? Then it will not work like this. As I said before - your current method is fine and there is no reason to change it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will look deeper into this.

Comment: Your second method worked very well and it makes a lot of sense since in LinqExpression `@Html.DatabaseImage(modeItem => item.Picture)` a delegate is being returned and htmlHelper.ViewData.Model is the parameter being passed to that delegate. But I have one question, does the compiler not check the type of htmlHelper.ViewData.Model at compile time? Its not known at compile time that its a byte array (I am not sure about this part), so why doesn't the compiler complain when we build the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, please disregard my last question in above comment. The delegate func is returning a byte[] according to the signature, so compiler knows it already, and therefore doesn't complain.

Comment: @Sunil in second method we use `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. On this type, `htmlHelper.ViewData.Model` is of type `TModel` (unlike in first example, where it's of type `object`). So it's safe to use, because it cannot fail at runtime like first method (will instead fail at compile time in this case).

Comment: Yes, I get it. And we already said that return type is byte[] so compiler will automatically know that `var dastabaseImage` is of type `byte[]`